# Is Table the only layout that I can use in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I'm looking for the common way to handle the layout in libgdx.
I searched google and found only table layout.
Meanwhile I don't use any layout and just insert coordination into each visual object but I think that this is not the proper way to do it...
Is their any other layout that I can use?

p.s
The game layout should split into two parts, left is smaller that the right and contains things like score time and info about stuff in the game. The right part will display the game-play itself

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. `Table` is just a tool and you should use it when it fits your desired result. If your widgets are supposed to be laid out in a tabular way, then  use `Table`. Otherwise, it's perfectly okay to position your widgets manually if that's what you need.

**Two alternatives to `Table`**

- [HorizontalGroup](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/HorizontalGroup.html): Just one example of a component made specifically for helping with with your layout. It seems to be what you are looking for.
- Two [Stage](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html) instances: have one `Stage` for the game area and one for the interface. Each `Stage` will have its own camera, which means you can move the game camera around the world while the interface camera stays still. To control how large each `Stage` is and where it is positioned, read about [Viewports on the LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

**When positioning manually**

One piece advice, though, if you decide to position your widgets manually: don't use absolute pixel coordinates. If you your screen is 400px wide and you want a widget's X coordinate to be 200px, set it to `0.5f * screenWidth`, instead. This will allow your widgets to be position correctly, even if the screen size changes and it takes no extra effort on your part.

---

**Edit:** The `HorizontalGroup` should have two children: a `InterfaceWidget` and a `GameWidget`. The `InterfaceWidget` will have as children all the things you want to appear in the left of the screen, such as score. The `GameWidget` will be the parent of the `PlayerActor` and any other actors you have in your game.

```
HorizontalGroup
  InterfaceWidget
    ScoreWidget
    SomeOtherWidget
  GameWidget
    PlayerActor
    SomeOtherActor
```

Comment: So if I understand you, I need to use two stages with horizontal group and the left stage will contain vertical group?

p.s my world doesn't move. Its something like board game.

Comment: @11alex11 Either choose `HorizontalGroup` or two `Stage` instances. But since your world doesn't move, the `HorizontalGroup` is a better solution because it's simpler. :)

Comment: I am new to libgdx and I think that I'm missing something.

On the right side of the screen I have only actors that I add randomly (x,y) in some range. the left side is also actors (score,time atc'...)

I don't see how I need to work with HorizontalGroup..

Comment: @11alex11 See the edit I made to my answer.